# VBA check if columns contains specific value

Tags: vba, excel, boolean

How can I find if columns contain TRUE or FALSE VALUE?

Answer (score 4):

As an example, you could evaluate cell `A1` like this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Select Case Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        Case True
            MsgBox "Cell A1 is TRUE"
        Case False
            MsgBox "Cell A1 is FALSE"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Cell A1 is neither True nor False"
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

### Edit:

Here is an alternative solution, since perhaps the goal is more of a "T/F Summary" for the ***entire*** column:

```
Sub Demo2()

    Dim cntT As Long, cntF As Long, resp As String
    cntT = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A"), True)
    cntF = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A"), False)

    Select Case cntT
        Case Is > 0
            Select Case cntF
                Case Is > 0
                    resp = "a mix of " & cntT & " TRUE and " & cntF & " FALSE."
                Case Else
                    resp = cntT & " TRUE but no FALSE."
            End Select
        Case Else
            Select Case cntF
                Case Is > 0
                    resp = cntF & " FALSE but no TRUE."
                Case Else
                    resp = "neither TRUE nor FALSE."
            End Select
    End Select

    MsgBox "The column contains " & resp, vbInformation

End Sub
```

### Example Output:

[image: img]

Comment: Nice and simple.

Comment: I normally like your answers, but this one seems to miss the requirement of checking the entire column. So I posted an alternative approach. I still gave you a tick because I'm trying to get the "I'm a good f*ing sportsman!" badge! 

Comment: @PGCodeRider - Holy cow, how did I get 40 points on this answer?!  Honestly it was a last-answer of the  day, and was sort of a tongue-in-cheek "half-assed" response to a "quarter-assed" question. (Not only was the word "entire" not included in the question, but neither was any other insight/explanation/example/background, *and* OP hasn't been back since.) I appreciate the tick even if selfishly motivated; I've returned the favour. Also I hadn't heard of the [sportsmanship badge](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) before, but suddenly I need it more than *anything.*

Comment: @PGCodeRider - Just since you said you're normally a fan of my answers, I felt obligated to put a tad more effort in, while using a method not already mentioned here.  Let me know if any of my other answers are below par.  (Seriously - please do! Constructive criticism is always important!)  :-)

Comment: @PGCodeRider  ...and now that i re-read the question is could be interpreted even more ways depending on which letter or word is missing... ie, *How can I find if columns contain a TRUE or FALSE value?* versus *How can I find if columns contain TRUE or FALSE values?* versus *How can I find which columns contain a TRUE or FALSE value?*, etc...

Comment: @ashleedawg if the OP reworded the question then it's totally excusable that your answer was off. That's essentially why I was surprised by it. Makes much more sense now. I like your new solution and glad you adopted the `CountIf` approach. I too like healthy criticism, but I probably won't go trolling through your previous work looking for improvements. Most of your stuff I've seen is solid. My answers tend to be pretty similar... "run a `For Each Loop` and do something!" 

Comment: @ashleedawg. As if to proove my point... some new question came up and sure enough, my answer is a `For Each Loop` DO SOMTHING! 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469074/vba-macro-delete-cells-containing-n-a-and-shift-up-the-cells-not-the-rows

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(TRUE,A:A),IFERROR(NOT(LOOKUP(FALSE,A:A)),"NEITHER FOUND"))
```

Or

```
=IFERROR(IF(LOOKUP(TRUE,A:A),TRUE,IF(NOT(LOOKUP(FALSE,A:A)),FALSE)),"NEITHER FOUND")
```

Or

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=TRUE))>0,"True found",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=FALSE))>0,"FALSE FOUND",))
```

Or

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Demo()
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    Const COL_NUMBER As Long = 1                     '< =Col A
    arr = Array(True, False)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not ActiveSheet.Columns(COL_NUMBER).Find(arr(i)) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox arr(i) & " found in column " & COL_NUMBER
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Neither True not False Found"
End Sub
```

---

As a function  call (to allow you an easy way to use as UDF in a sheet passing a column in as range argument):

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Const COL_NUMBER As Long = 1     '< =Col A
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(COL_NUMBER)
    MsgBox IsTrueOrFalseFound(rng)
End Sub
Public Function IsTrueOrFalseFound(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = Array(True, False)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not rng.Find(arr(i)) Is Nothing Then
            IsTrueOrFalseFound = arr(i) & " found in column " & rng.Column
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsTrueOrFalseFound = "Neither True not False Found"
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first two answers posted are too complex based on the succinct requirements the OP lists. A `CountIF` approach seems like the most efficient approach.

Ignoring the OP title, the answer does not even require VBA. It can just be a cell formula:

**Test if True Found:**

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,TRUE)>0,"There's a TRUE in the Column!","No true's found!")`

**Test if True OR False found:**

`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,TRUE)+COUNTIF(B:B,FALSE)>0,"There's either a True or False FOUND!","Nothing found")`

If this activity does need to be referenced in VBA, then you can use a similar approach.

```
Dim SrchRNG As Range
Set SrchRNG = Range("B:B")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SrchRNG, True) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SrchRNG, False) > 0 Then
    'Here's when a true or false has been found
Else
    'Code if neither is found
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner, which returns true if a match was found and false if no match was found:

```
Debug.Print Not IsError(Application.Match(True, Range("A:A"), 0))
```

The code above checks for the boolean value `True`, but if you want to check for the string "True", simply insert "True" in the first parameter instead.