# VBA macro delete cells containing #N/A and shift up the cells (not the rows)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a ranking and I need to delete all the cells with #N/A (pasted as text, not formula) and to delete those cells and shhift them up.

The worksheet contains 503 raws and I need it from column A to T. 
[image]

Thanks in advance, I have tried so many VBA codes of this web and I'm not able to find something that works.

Comment: what have you done yourself? you need to provide a sample, snapshot does not do it

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
dim rng as range

with worksheets("sheet1")
    on error resume next
    set rng = .range("A:T").specialcells(xlcelltypeformulas, xlerrors)
    if not rng is nothing then
        rng.delete shift:=xlup
    end if
    set rng = .range("A:T").specialcells(xlcelltypeconstants, xlerrors)
    if not rng is nothing then
        rng.delete shift:=xlup
    end if        
    on error goto 0
end with
```

Comment: what error are you anticipating? Just curious since you are already checking if the rng is nothing.

Comment: @urdearboy I had the same question and went and tested. Sure enough, `specialcells` will throw an error when setting a range with nothing found, which is different than regular range setting. @Jeeped, another answer that is f*ing cool. I seem to always be upvoting your answers that compete against me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. There are faster ways of doing what you ask, but since you don't have that big of a data set, I just modified some code I had available.

```
Sub KillPoundNa()
Dim rCell As Range, WS As Worksheet, KillRng As Range, UndesireableText As String

UndesireableText = "#N/A"
Set WS = ActiveSheet

Set KillRng = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)

For Each rCell In WS.UsedRange.Cells

    If InStr(1, rCell.Text, UndesireableText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set KillRng = Union(KillRng, rCell)
    End If

Next rCell

KillRng.Delete (xlUp)

End Sub
```

Comment: @jeeped answer is better. I'm just leaving mine up as an alternative and so I can get points for voting his answer up because I'm going for the "I'm a gosh dang great sporstmanship!" Badge...